# Django not rendering CSS correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a site that I'm creating, part in static HTML, the other part is served via Django.  Since I want the look and feel to remain the same (who doesn't?) I have used CSS for the static site.  That same CSS I have included (almost successfully) in the dynamic site.

When I create a form, I can get a very nice two column listing on the static side

```
Label  Input
Label  Input
Label  Input
```

But, when I do the same code on the dynamic side, it's not so nice

```
Label  Input
       Label  Input
              Label  Input
```

The CSS I'm using is:

```
form.login label.fixedwidth {
   display: block;
   width: 240px;
   float: left;
}
```

\.
Sorry, here's my form:

```
     <form action="" method="post" class="login">
        <fieldset>
           <div>
              <label for="username" class="fixedwidth">User name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
           </div>
           <div>
              <label for="password" class="fixedwidth">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">
           </div>
           <input type="submit" value="login" /> 
        </fieldset>
     </form>
```

[edit]
So, I noticed that my two 'input type' lines didn't close the tag (no '/').  But, no difference.
[/edit]

Comment: Django has nothing to do with CSS. It seems obvious that the HTML of Django's forms is different to the HTML of your static form. Is the HTML you pasted from your static, or from a Django template? It would be helpful to post both so we can compare the two.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, which is why I was so surprised to see different results.  The HTML is the same, I cut/paste from one to the other to start the debug of this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
clear:both; overflow: auto
```

on the surrounding DIV.

By the way, a `<ul>` with `<li>` s may be semantically more fitting than `<div>`s here. Won't make a difference in the output though.

Comment: clear:both had no affect, and the ul/li option just added bullets -- yes, I know I can get rid of them, but it made no diff in my error :)

Comment: Oh forgot one, see my answer.

Comment: When I added those tags to my div's, no change.  But, when I added clear:both (only) to my 'form.login label.fixedwidth {}', everything looks good.

Comment: Huh? That's not what I expected to happen. But anyway, if it works it works! :)